# Unwanted space after using a glossary term

Tags: glossaries

I have a problem with using the glossary package. I use sharelatex.

When I use a glossary term (first and others), there appears an unwanted space in the output document.

This is the code I use:

Main

```
\usepackage[acronym, translate=babel, nopostdot]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

% External files
\loadglsentries{Z_glossary}
\loadglsentries{Z_afkortingen}

% Not in table of contents
\glstocfalse

% First appearance in italic
\defglsdisplayfirst[\glsdefaulttype]{\textit{#1}}
```

The Glossary

```
\newglossaryentry{workflowpattern}%
{%
    name={Workflowpattern}, 
    description={Blablabla}, 
    text={workflowpattern}, 
    plural={workflowpatterns}, 
    first={workflowpattern},            
    firstplural={workflowpatterns},
}
```

The text

```
zijn de \glspl{workflowpattern} en beschrijven
```

And the result:

[image: The output]

Comment: On behalf of @Gary Wang, `"The bug mentioned by **Heiko Oberdiek** has been fixed in the newest version of glossaries (4.42) where the needless space has been removed. So there should be no extra space."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unwanted space comes from `\defglsdisplayfirst` of glossaries.sty 2014/01/20 v4.03, see the line marked with `% <==`:

```
\newcommand*{\defglsdisplayfirst}[2][\glsdefaulttype]{%
  \GlossariesWarning{\string\defglsdisplayfirst\space is now obsolete.^^J
  Use \string\defglsentryfmt\space instead}%
  \expandafter\def\csname gls@#1@displayfirst\endcsname##1##2##3##4{#2}%
  \edef\@gls@doentrydef{%
    \noexpand\defglsentryfmt[#1]{%
      \noexpand\ifcsdef{gls@#1@display}%
      {%
        \noexpand\@@gls@default@entryfmt
          {\noexpand\csuse{gls@#1@displayfirst}}
          {\noexpand\csuse{gls@#1@display}}%
      }%
      {%
        \noexpand\@@gls@default@entryfmt
          {\noexpand\csuse{gls@#1@displayfirst}}%
          {\noexpand\glsdisplay} % <==
      }%
    }%  
  }%
  \@gls@doentrydef
}
```

As workaround, the definition without the unwanted space:

```
\usepackage[...]{glossaries}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\defglsdisplayfirst}[2][\glsdefaulttype]{%
  \GlossariesWarning{\string\defglsdisplayfirst\space is now obsolete.^^J
  Use \string\defglsentryfmt\space instead}%
  \expandafter\def\csname gls@#1@displayfirst\endcsname##1##2##3##4{#2}%
  \edef\@gls@doentrydef{%
    \noexpand\defglsentryfmt[#1]{%
      \noexpand\ifcsdef{gls@#1@display}%
      {%
        \noexpand\@@gls@default@entryfmt
          {\noexpand\csuse{gls@#1@displayfirst}}
          {\noexpand\csuse{gls@#1@display}}%
      }%
      {%
        \noexpand\@@gls@default@entryfmt
          {\noexpand\csuse{gls@#1@displayfirst}}%
          {\noexpand\glsdisplay}% without unwanted space
      }%
    }%  
  }%
  \@gls@doentrydef
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to place it before

    \defglsdisplayfirst[\glsdefaulttype]{\textit{#1}}

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\defglsdisplayfirst[\glsdefaulttype]{\textit{#1}\ignorespaces}
```